# AngularJs - how to disable the view/template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is my issue:
(Please bear with me if that is easy/stupid question, I am new to Angular :) )
I am loading a page with angular where I have 3 tabs (and so 3 contents) which are using the tabs.
So when I land on my page, all the three tabs and content are generated.

My problem is that when I click on a different tab, the link matches the route, and I guess go back to the controller and render the view again.

My thoughts about this issue is to disable the view when I go to my controller the second time, but can't find any way of doing that.

As said, I am kind of new on angular, so if you think I should do things differently, any comments are welcome :)

Here is my view:

```
<div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
  <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" role="presentation">
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" role="presentation">
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in" role="tabpanel">
    <div ng-include src="'/path/includes/tab1.htm'"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
    <div ng-include src="'/path/includes/tab2.htm'"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
    <div ng-include src="'/path/includes/tab3.htm'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is where I catch the route in the controller:

```
.when('/url/:intUserId?', {
    controller:'ViewApiCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/path/view-api.htm',
})
```

Let me know if I should post more info about my code !

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**
Basically I don't want to only return the content of one tab only, or just display one tab at a time.
For this example here, my 3 tabs are one big form, with some inputs on the 3 different tabs.
So it doesnt matter on what tab the user is, he can change a field on one, switch tab, click on save on the second tab and it will save the whole form.
What I am looking for is something like, when I switch tab, let bootstrap handle the display, and I want Angular to not doo anything ( so if it goes to the controller, exit it straight away and dont render/reload the template).

Thanks Michel for the tips, I think it will be useful on my other pages with tabs that are not really linked to each other (I can load one without the others), but for this particular case, I don't think it will suit me :(

On `php` using `Zend Framework`, I used to do it that way if that helps:

> Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout(); 
>   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender( true);

Comment: You could try to use the `ng-if` directive to not render the tab when the condition is not met.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to load the 3 tabs at the same time (the first time I load the page), and then just display the active content / hide the other tabs (done y bootstrap). The 'ng-if' would just render one tab at a time, which is not exactly what I am looking for :(

Comment: Then, taking in account that you want just do display conditionally, you can use the `ng-hide` or `ng-show` directives, that accept expressions as well

Comment: I have just edited my post to make it a bit more clear. But I think your idea will be useful for other cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so with your latest edit, with bootstrap you can do [that](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), and with angular-ui [as well](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)!

Just put your tabs inside the form and when you submit all the data is submitted as well!

Comment: Unfortunatly, this solution is already what I am doing, but it doesnt solve my issue. When I click on a new tab, it still regenerates the view, which is not what I am expecting :(